# Openstack Keystone show "HTTPUnauthorized at /project/instances/"

Tags: openstack

I installed Ceilometer for openstack, and this is Create the appropriate users and roles for ceilometer:

```
SERVICE_TENANT=$(keystone tenant-list | grep service | awk '{print $2}')
ADMIN_ROLE=$(keystone role-list | grep ' admin ' | awk '{print $2}')
SERVICE_PASSWORD=servicepass
CEILOMETER_USER=$(keystone user-create --name=ceilometer \
  --pass="$SERVICE_PASSWORD" \
  --tenant_id $SERVICE_TENANT \
  --email=ceilometer@example.com | awk '/ id / {print $4}')
RESELLER_ROLE=$(keystone role-create --name=ResellerAdmin | awk '/ id / {print $4}')
ADMIN_ROLE=$(keystone role-list | awk '/ admin / {print $2}')
for role in $RESELLER_ROLE $ADMIN_ROLE ; do
  keystone user-role-add --tenant_id $SERVICE_TENANT \
   --user_id $CEILOMETER_USER --role_id $role
done
```

It appears this error "Exception Value: HTTPUnauthorized (HTTP 401)
Exception Location:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ceilometerclient/common/http.py in _http_request, line 165" when I use "admin" register a user and click /project/instances.
I think that there is an error when I create the appropriate users and roles for ceilometer.
Could someone give me some advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpcode= 401 indicates that your authentication details are incorrect. If you are using service password then crosscheck it with admin_token in keystone.conf

```
grep admin_token /etc/keystone/keystone.conf | awk '{print $3}'
```

In addition, note that ,you will receive 401 Unauthorized for a user created in a tenant but have **"NO ROLES"** assigned to it .